# failed to enable VT-x in bios system in ubuntu 16.04 LTS(AMD FX(tm)-4100 Quad-Core Processor)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install android studio in my ubuntu system.But when I open the AVD manager it shows following warning message
[image]

after searching on internet I understand that I need to goto bios setup->advanced->intel virtualization technology(enable it if it is disabled),
but I can't find intel virtualization technology option in my bios setup.

**bios menu**
[image]
[image]
how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your board doesn't support VT-x. You are looking at the right spot I beleive. I must say, it has been a long time since I've seen such a board.

Have you correctly checked if your board supports VT-x ? Best way to find out is to check the specs of your computer/motherboard online.

Keep us posted, and good luck,

Clovel

## EDIT : AMD-V / AMD IOMMU

It seems [here](https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html) that for AMD processors, the option you are looking for is AMD-V (VT-x counterpart) & AMD IOMMU (VTd counterpart ?). See if you can enable either one of these options in `Advanced -> CPU Options`